# Where is the drive-belt tensioner, on a Renault Sandero K7M 1.6 8v?

Tags: serpentine-belt, drive-belt

Whilst replacing my drive-belt on a renault sandero 1.6 8v, I have tried to turn two of the pulleys/wheels to see if they will allow slack for replacing my drive-belt(using a hand-spanner) but neither of the 2 most likely candidates is budging.

Is there simple a way to find the tensioner? Should I just apply more force in case the tensioner is one of these and is a bit stuck?

Comment: Which drive configuration does your engine have? Does it have power steering and/or air condition? From what I'm reading, it could have AC and PS, just PS, or just AC, so three different configurations. Each one has a different tensioner setup. https://aubito.ru/en/renault-sandero/checking-and-replacing-the-accessory-drive-belt-renault-sandero

Comment: It has both AC and PS, @Paulster2.

Comment: [If this image looks like your configuration](https://aubito.ru/images/stories/sand/dvig/srem3.JPG), your tensioner should be #2. You'd turn it clockwise using the bolt head to turn it.

Comment: Hmmm.... that is the same as my drawing.

But #2 is not budging... let me have one more go.

Comment: Yes... it's going nowhere.

Comment: Btw, @Paulster2, just a thought... does the right-hand drive version look any different to the left-hand drive version?

It's a bit hard to tell, with the foreign language.

Comment: It shouldn't. The engine still runs in the same direction. They aren't going to completely redesign everything on the engine because it's right hand drive.

Comment: Okay. Btw, I managed to work the tensioner into yielding, so it is moving now but I want to know something which is probably a new question so thanks for your help on this one @Paulster2. (I will mark as answered if I see the check mark.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this image, the belt tensioner is located at #14. You should put a wench (spanner) on the center bolt and turn it clockwise:

[image]